# Preparing y_target variable for Neural Network training

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have the array for `y_target` variable, which have the shape `(5000,)` and I would like to use it for Keras NN models for time series classification.

Using numpy `newaxis` I have converted the dimension from 1D to 2D by doing the following: `y_target = y_target[..., newaxis]`

My target variable has 2 classes: `[0,1]` so the array from the last converting (shape `(5000,1)`). And looks like this:

```
[[0],
 [0],
 [1],
 [0],
 [1]]
```

I would like to transform this array using the following logics: `(5000,2)` which will have binary structure like this:

```
 [[1, 0],
  [1, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [1, 0],
  [0, 1]]
```

Is there a straight forward approach to do that in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the point how to do that :)

One possible way is to use `Keras` library and `to_categorical()` function

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_target = to_categorical(y_target)
```